# How javascript || (or) operator works

Tags: javascript, operators, conditional-statements, or-operator

In the following JavaScript statement:

```
var a = true;
a = a || b;
```

Will the `a` variable have an unneeded reasignment to it's own value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will assign to `a`. This sort of thing probably wouldn't even be optimised in a compiled language.

It won't however waste time evaluating `b` however as it knows the result already. Something like this happens when `a = a || b` is run:

```
if a
    a = a
else
    a = b
```

**EDIT:**

To follow up what icktoofay said "it will not significantly impact performance.", it is simply setting a (boolean) variable which is one of the simplest operations that can occur. It will make little difference even if you're assigning to something more significant like a function or array as it will be assigning to a reference of the item, not creating it again.

Here is a performance comparison of doing nothing vs assigning to self ([jsPerf link](http://jsperf.com/reassign-to-self)) thanks to [@bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445359/how-javascript-or-operator-works#comment21851068_15445384) for setting it up.

Comment: It would be `else` not `else if` right? Cause if `a` and `b` are `false` a will still get assigned to `b`.

Comment: Yes, I'm mainly trying to illustrating that it skips b if a has been evaluated.

Comment: I see your point. I'll be accepting your answer in a few minutes, though I'd love to see additional info on the subject.

Comment: I used a boolean value just as a short example. Do you think it'd have more of a performance hike if it was a large function or something?

Comment: No, it should make little difference as setting to a function would be pointing to a reference of the function, not creating it again.

Comment: @bfavaretto +1 I see I have nothing to worry about! :)

Answer (score 0):

`a` will be true when `a` or `b` is true. So yes, unless you insert some more code between those lines which can affect the value of `a`, the lower statement will always set `a` to true.

Comment: This is incorrect. If `b` is `true`, but `a` is, for example, `10`, then `a`will be reassigned to `10`, not `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it won't be optimised away, because JavaScript doesn't optimise. Although the underlying parser implementation could conceivably optimise, I very much doubt it would in this case, and it would be very specific to the platform implementation.